# Returning a composite graphics object in python/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to produce a filled contour plot with a few individual contour lines and a colorbar, rather like the "Lines with colorbar" plot over at the matplotlib [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html)  The thing is that, after I have my routine produce this thing, I don't want to display it immediately.  I want the routine to return it for some further optional processing.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: What type of optional processing?

Comment: Mainly I was thinking about monkeying with the axis labels of the main plot (giving the user choices of units, how many ticks to display, stuff like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have **not** turned on interactive mode (i.e. by calling `plt.ion()`), your drawing will not be displayed until you call

```
plt.show()
```

So, to continue drawing on the same axis, just continue calling drawing function such as `plt.plot` or `plt.contourf`, etc.
Whether these calls originate from the routine or not does not matter).

Comment: Well, that was simple enough, and it looks like you're right.  Thanks!